# Java complex calculation from a file using threads (concurrency)

Tags: java, parallel-processing

So I have text files that I can parse with the code I have and make the calculations for some atoms in space. Thing is I have to make the program parallel using threads and I don't know how I am supposed to pass the text file in every thread.

If I try to do something like `double kx = console.nextDouble();` it doesn't recognize what console is because its `Scanner` object inside of `main()`. What am I missing?

(Note: it's not strictly necessary to use threads directly; I could use fork-join pool, etc.)

```java
    public class NBodyBH {

    //Set value to simulate <execTime> seconds of the bodies
    static final int execTime = 100;

    static final boolean draw = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fname = args[0];
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(fname));
        System.setIn(is);

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        final double dt = 0.1;                     // time quantum
        int N = console.nextInt();                 // number of particles
        double radius = console.nextDouble();      // radius of universe

        //BELOW HERE IS THE PART I WANT TO MAKE PARALLEL
        Body[] bodies = new Body[N];               // array of N bodies
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            double px = console.nextDouble();
            double py = console.nextDouble();
            double vx = console.nextDouble();
            double vy = console.nextDouble();
            double mass = console.nextDouble();
            int red = console.nextInt();
            int green = console.nextInt();
            int blue = console.nextInt();
            Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
            bodies[i] = new Body(px, py, vx, vy, mass, color);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is [AsynchronousFileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html). It was introduced in Java 7 for async operations on files.

Although, you're saying you'll run a complex calculation so maybe the time intensive task is the calculation itself instead of the file reading, you could read the file in your main thread and use parallelism to run the complex calculations.

```
List<Integer> calculationResults = bodies.parallelStream()
                                         .map(doComplexCalculation)
                                         .collect(toList())
```

In the example I'm assuming the calculation returns an `Integer` and that `bodies` is a `Collection` like a `List`, but adapt it as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the file to each thread sounds like a bad idea. Then you'd have to coordinate which thread reads which data, which would be unnecessarily complicated, or (more likely), each thread needs all the data, and making each thread re-read the file is inefficient.

First, read all the data. Then pass each thread the data it needs.

Don't assign your new `FileInputStream` to `System.in`. Just create a `Scanner` with it directly:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get(arg[0]));
...
List<Body> bodies = new ArrayList<>(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
   ...
   bodies.add(new Body(...));
}
for (int step = 0; step < 10; ++step) { /* Simulate 10 time steps, or whatever. */
    List<Body> next = bodies.parallelStream() /* Here's your threads. */
        .map(body -> step(body, dt, bodies))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    /* Render new state */
    ...
    bodies = next; /* Throw away your old state. */
}
```

Here, `step()` is a function you need to write. If I've guessed what you are doing correctly, it will create a clone of the body, with a new position and velocity, based on the positions of the others. If you can modify the code of the `Body` class, this method should probably be a member of that class.

You must be careful not to modify the "current" bodies, but only create replacement for each. This upholds the "non-interference" requirement of `Stream` parallelism. Each time step will take O(N<sup>2</sup>) time to compute, since each new state of each body (N) depends on the state of every other body (× N).

Comment: Ok but the txt file is 1000 lines long. And for example i have to split it into 4 threads of 250 lines each. How can i pass each thread the data i need after i read the file?